# Custom page number positioning in a rotated A4 environment

Tags: numbering, rotating

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{9}
TEST
\end{document}
```

The issue here is that the footer of my page is now on the side of the normal A4 format.

If I run this, the page number 9 will end up at the bottom of the rotated page.

What I want to do is the following:

- Either rotate the text I have on my page (not really the solution I'm looking for, but it would work) or
- Force the page number to appear in the same place as when I didn't rotate the entire page.

Comment: use lscape package and landscape environment will rotate the page body while leaving the page head and foot